# Visual Studio - Customise run action to use DebugAdapterHost.launch

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, .net-core, remote-debugging

Is it possible in Visual Studio 2017 to change the action performed by the green debug button and the F5 hotkey.

Currently I have to publish my .net core console application (using a profile I have created) and then in the command window (View->Other Windows->Command Window) execute "DebugAdapterHost.Launch /LaunchJson:somepathblahblah".

This is based off of https://github.com/Microsoft/MIEngine/wiki/Offroad-Debugging-of-.NET-Core-on-Linux---OSX-from-Visual-Studio

However, I always want to be remote debugging my application, so changing the default debug action to somehow perform those two steps would save a lot of time. Even if it can't perform the publish step, doing the DebugAdapterHost.Launch command would be great!

Comment: It seems you have to create a visual studio command by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Alex, calling `DebugAdapterHost.launch` as customised run action is not possible.

But [here is an extension](https://github.com/LukeOwlclaw/RemoteDebugLauncher) which builds the current project and afterwards invokes the `DebugAdapterHost.Launch` command.

[Your own approach creating an extension which implements `IDebugProfileLaunchTargetsProvider`](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/3835) is of course another option.